# How can I call the Advanced settings page of the File History settings in Windows 10 Control Panel?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, control-panel, file-history

I would like to open the advanced settings directly by putting a command to `Windows` + `R`. So far I have only found out I can call the File History settings via `shell:::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}`. Then, you need to click the advanced settings link on the left, and this is what is I would like to automate.

Is there any command, any CLSID or [canonical name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741(v=vs.85).aspx) I can use to fulfill my wish?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: I would imagine the file history advanced settings would be simply registry values for the drive itself.  As for the CLSID, only one that exists, would be `Microsoft.FileHistory`.  The only group policy appears to be that to disable it, but without having to test it myself, I suspect if you specifically disabled the group policy, it might prevent a user from turning it off.

Comment: I'm sorry, l'm not clear on what you're suggesting. Why should I modify the registry? I'm just searching for a general preexisting command to open this settings window!

Comment: "I'm just searching for a general preexisting command to open this settings window!" - I am saying it doesn't exist and you might have to look to configuring it by modifying the registry, because this particular setting, is user specific.

Comment: Now I understand you. I always thought every control panel dialog page or windows had to be written into registry, but if is not possible, I will have to tell the user where to click and then call `shell:::{F6B6E965-E9B2-444B-9286-10C9152EDBC5}` directly.